# Can we create an app to kill all app in background without jailbreak

Tags: ios, jailbreak, springboard

I'v found an project that allow some action in SpringBoard so can we create an app to kill all apps running on the background??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can but you have to use the private framework **BackBoardServices** you can find the headers of this framework [here](https://github.com/Cykey/ios-reversed-headers/blob/master/BackBoardServices/BackBoardServices.h)

```
BKSTerminateApplicationGroupForReasonAndReportWithDescription(1, 5, 21, @"Kill all the apps");
```

or if you want to kill only a specific app

```
BKSTerminateApplicationForReasonAndReportWithDescription(@"com.apple.mobilesafari", 5, 1, @"Kill safari");
```

Comment: Can you give me your Twitter or FB account I need some help please

Comment: what help do u need ?

Comment: to create this simple app

Comment: @Karim code is not working in my project i need some help please

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 11 from my experience and I haven't found an alternative yet.